# Object is not iterable in django rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple view in DRF that looks like this:

```
class AdminDocumentListUpdateView(generics.ListAPIView, mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
    queryset = Document.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AdminDocumentSerializer
    pagination_class = None

def get_queryset(self):
    user_id = self.kwargs.get('user_id')
    qs = Document.objects.filter(user=user_id).latest('created_at')
    return qs
```

But the `get_queryset` function raises an error `'Document' object is not iterable`. This only happens when I add something like `latest('created_at')` or `first()` or I try to index the queryset (`[0]`). Why is this happening?

Comment: `Document.objects.filter(user=user_id).latest('created_at')` will return one object, so it may be because of serializers or other things that trying to iterate over this qs which in your case is one object and it is not iterable. that make sence

Comment: `get_queryset` supposed to return a QuerySet rather than a single object

Comment: What if the queryset consists of a single object?

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because get_queryset is expected to return a queryset(iterable), not an object. While the methods like first or latest returns an object instead of a queryset. So your get_queryset method returns a single object instead of a queryset.

[reference to get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset)

Comment: What about I supposed to do then?

Comment: If the queryset consists of a single object, it will work. Why do you want a single object in a list view though? ListView is for the list of objects.

Comment: It is a list view but if a param is passed then it should just return the latest object

Comment: What you can do is get the latest just like you are doing now, and then use its id in .filter method and return the result of that filter method. It will have a single object but in a queryset, so your result will be a list with one object. (but it is an extra hit to db)